# Cannot run turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is extremely frustrating. I am trying to run a very simple program and I can't even get it to work. I tried searching the forums and googling this specific error but I cannot find anything.

Here's what I wrote:

```
import turtle as t; t.forward(100)
```

Here s the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/dae.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle as t; t.forward(100)
  File "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32\turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    turtle.forward(100)
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward'
```

Please help

Comment: Post first few lines from `turtle.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has name `turtle.py` and that is why it is being imported in `import turtle as t; t.forward(100)` instead of original `turtle` module.

You have to rename your file in order to fix the issue.